# Printing a circle using arrow symbols

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, geometry, symbols

I have been struggling to draw a circle pattern using arrow symbols along with `delay();` or `Sleep();` like after printing `↑` it would delay for about a couple of seconds and then print  `→` and so on.   which would give an impression of a *drawing circle*. Something like

```
        ↑

   ←         →

        ↓
```

I have tried searching everywhere, and what I have found so far is *how to read the arrow keys* only or [VM_KEYDOWN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx). Sadly that's not what I want. Please help? Ps. I know I haven't posted any "Productive try" and that's because I dont have any so don't get mad :X 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

**UPDATED:**
I tried to print the arrows with this failed attempt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() { 
    std::wstring s(L"←→↑↓"); 
    std::wcout << s << "\n"; 
}
```

**UPDATED-2***
So I have managed to print the symbols with this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char left,right,up,down;

  up = 24;
  down = 25;
  left = 27;
  right = 26;

  cout << up;
  cout << down;
  cout << left;
  cout << right;
  cout << "\n";
  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

But now I need to know how to do it with a sequences as printed in above.

**Working Attempt**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char left, right, up, down;

    up = 24;
    down = 25;
    left = 27;
    right = 26;
    cout << setw(10);
    cout << up;
    cout << endl;
    cout << setw(20);
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << right;

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << setw(10);
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << down;
    Sleep(1000);

    cout << left;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

But this is clearly not accurate/efficient.

Comment: Do you want to do this in a graphics window or in a terminal ? Either way you'll need an external library, such as nCurses for terminal manipulation.

Comment: @Quentin Please elaborate? I intend to do this on a console (if that makes any sense) What kind of an external library? and I have read some about nCurses here: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-c-c-166055/ If that's correct

Comment: Then nCurses (PDCurses on Windows IIRC) is what you need. The documentation is [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/). [`keypad()`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/init.html#KEYPAD) is what you need for arrow keys functionality.

Comment: @Quentin keypad() will only allow on how to read the keys right? If so, I do know that but how do I draw them? That's the issue. Please help me with this!! :(

Comment: They are Unicode characters, you can output them either as wide chars with `addwch()`, or as UTF-8 sequence with  `addstr()`.

Comment: @Quentin see my updated question? can you please show me how exactly to do it? Please? :3

Comment: What is the result you get with that snippet ? On which terminal (console) ?

Comment: @Quentin I get nothing but a blank screen. VS2013? :$

Comment: So you just want to print arrow *symbols* ? If that is the case, you should remove the part about *keys*. This probably has to do with encoding and/or font used in the terminal.

Comment: @Leiaz Thanks for replying, well yes but I want them to be printed in a sequence such that it makes a circle like Ive described in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good to see that effort. I have made a few changes and added a function to set the cursor position to the same line where you've printed `→`. Try this:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    using namespace std;
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    COORD CursorPosition;
    void gotoXY(int, int);

    int main(){
    char left, right, up, down;
    up = 24;
    down = 25;
    left = 27;
    right = 26;
    cout << setw(20) << up<< endl << endl << endl<< setw(25);
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << right << endl<< endl<< endl << setw(20);
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << down;
    Sleep(1000);
    cout << endl;
    gotoXY(0, 2 + (1));
    cout << setw(15) << left<< endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
   }
    void gotoXY(int x, int y)
    {
        CursorPosition.X = x;
        CursorPosition.Y = y;
        SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, CursorPosition);
    }
```

> I admit it isn't that efficient either but it works and it should help
>   you understand/move forward better.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, I know what to do next. Thankyouuu soo muchh!!

Comment: You can shorten your code by removing multiple couts. Like `cout << setw(20) << up << endl << endl << endl << setw(25);`

Comment: @Undefined Im glad it helped :)